# How to succesfully run a batch file in an SQL Agent job?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent, jobs

I have a SQL Agent Job which generates a specific report in PDF-file and then copies the PDF to a network directory and then deletes the PDF file in the source directory.

The SQL Jobs consists of 2 steps:
1. Generate the report
2. Copy the report to the network location.

For step 2 I made a bat-file which handles the copying and removal of the pdf file.

The bat-file is as follows:

```
set source_dir=C:\Reports\Energie\Uur
set dest_dir=\\KWS2-WEB-SERVER\Share\Reports\Uur

C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe %source_dir% %dest_dir% /MOV /Z
```

***However, when I run my the Job, it hangs on the second step. The status just stays on "Executing".***

This is the line which I stated in the step (location of the bat-file to execute):

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\Reports\rapport_uur_copy.bat"
```

My job-settings are as follows:

**Step 1**

Type: Operating system (CmdExec)
On Success: Go to the next step

On Failure: Quit the job reporting failure

**Step 2**

Type: Operating system (CmdExec)

On Success: Quit the job reporting success

On Failure: Quit the job reporting failure

**Some facts:**

- I have read/write permissions on the network directory
- I run the steps as the Administrator-account (the logged in user, default)
- Step 1 succeeds
- I run Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
- I have SQL Server 2008 R2
- When I run the script from the cmd manually, it works (under Administrator account).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to configure the second step of your job to run as a domain account with permissions to write to the **\KWS2-WEB-SERVER\Share\Reports\Uur** share as well as read access to the **C:\Reports\Energie\Uur** folder.

You first will need to add a credential to SQL Server. From the **Security > Credentials** folder you will need to right click and choose **New Credential...** Fill in that information and click OK.

Once that is complete you will need to create a Proxy that uses this credential. From the **SQL Server Agent > Proxies > Operating System (CmdExec)** folder you will need to right click and choose **New Proxy...** Use the credential you created earlier.

Now you can configure your second job step to use the Proxy you just created using **Run As:** drop down of the job step page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I the steps you explained are already present in my configuration. (It was unclear in my first-post, my bad)

I have a credential named "asAdmin"
The identity is as follows: _KWS2_SCADA_SERV\Administrator_

Then I created a proxy named "AsAdminProxy". I selected the appropriate credentials and selected _"Operating system (CmdExec)_" as the active subsystem. Also, when I look into the "References" tab I see all the job steps, including the one which doesn't run. So i think it is correctly condigured.

Answer (score 2):

Typically when a job like this hangs it is because the command execution is waiting for a response.  Because any command execution run from SQL Server is run as a shell, and you can't see the shell, it can't get a response.  If I were you I would try running the bat file manually and see if you are asked for a response.  If so correct that part (so that it doesn't ask for a response) and try again.

If running it yourself doesn't help then try running it through xp_cmdshell and see if you get any output back.  It may still hang though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue.  My SQL job would hang and say "Executing..." and never complete.

Add "--trust-model always"  to your .bat file.

Basically your .bat file runs when you run it manually because you're the owner.  It trusts you.  When you run the .bat as a different user, the cmd will actually display a warning and ask you if you trust it.  Your job is hanging because the cmd is waiting for your answer.  Adding "--trust-model always" will skip this question and allow the .bat to finish.

Trust me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Every step you seperate with \CR \LF in a Script you have written previously only can be executed in the AgentJob if you choose one of those two options:

- Everey seperate line in your bat-script hast to be a seperate step in the AgentJob
- delete all \CR \LF and in your Step of the AgentJob and put a `&&` between your commands

Answer (score -1):

Try using COMSPEC to run the .bat using a .CMD file

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. As valid as your suggestion may be we appreciate it if you explain why as well

Comment: Sorry I don't have my example but I used this years ago to run oracle, dos, and other commands as a .BAT file but for a reason I can't remember I had to used COMSPEC